# mfc tab control switch tabs

Tags: c++, mfc, cdialog

I created a simple tab control that has 2 tabs (each tab is a different dialog). The thing is that i don't have any idea how to switch between tabs (when the user presses `Titlu Tab1` to show the dialog i made for the first tab, and when it presses `Titlu Tab2` to show my other dialog). I added a handler for changing items, but i don't know how should i acces some kind of index or child for tabs.

`Tab1.h` and `Tab2.h` are headers for dialogs that show only static texts with the name of the each tab.

There may be an obvious answer to my question, but i am a real newbie in c++ and MFC.

This is my header:

```
// CTabControlDlg.h : header file
//

#pragma once
#include "afxcmn.h"
#include "Tab1.h"
#include "Tab2.h"


// CCTabControlDlg dialog
class CCTabControlDlg : public CDialog
{
// Construction
public:
   CCTabControlDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor

// Dialog Data
enum { IDD = IDD_CTABCONTROL_DIALOG };

protected:
virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support


// Implementation
protected:
   HICON m_hIcon;

  // Generated message map functions
  virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
  afx_msg void OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam);
  afx_msg void OnPaint();
  afx_msg HCURSOR OnQueryDragIcon();
  DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
  CTabCtrl m_tabcontrol1;

  CTab1 m_tab1;
  CTab2 m_tab2;
  afx_msg void OnTcnSelchangeTabcontrol(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult);
};
```

And this is the .cpp:

```
// CTabControlDlg.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CTabControl.h"
#include "CTabControlDlg.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// CAboutDlg dialog used for App About

class CAboutDlg : public CDialog
{
 public:
   CAboutDlg();

 // Dialog Data
  enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX };

  protected:
  virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

 // Implementation
 protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
 };

 CAboutDlg::CAboutDlg() : CDialog(CAboutDlg::IDD)
 {
 }

 void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
 {
   CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
 }

 BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAboutDlg, CDialog)
 END_MESSAGE_MAP()


 // CCTabControlDlg dialog




 CCTabControlDlg::CCTabControlDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
   : CDialog(CCTabControlDlg::IDD, pParent)
 {
   m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
 }

 void CCTabControlDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
 {
  CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
  DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_TABCONTROL, m_tabcontrol1);
 }

 BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CCTabControlDlg, CDialog)
  ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
  ON_WM_PAINT()
  ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
  //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
  ON_NOTIFY(TCN_SELCHANGE, IDC_TABCONTROL,         &CCTabControlDlg::OnTcnSelchangeTabcontrol) 
    END_MESSAGE_MAP()


   // CCTabControlDlg message handlers

  BOOL CCTabControlDlg::OnInitDialog()
  {
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    // Add "About..." menu item to system menu.

    // IDM_ABOUTBOX must be in the system command range.
    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != NULL)
{
    CString strAboutMenu;
    strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
    if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
    {
        pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
        pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
    }
}

// Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
//  when the application's main window is not a dialog
SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

// TODO: Add extra initialization here

CTabCtrl* pTabCtrl = (CTabCtrl*)GetDlgItem(IDC_TABCONTROL);

m_tab1.Create(IDD_TAB1, pTabCtrl);

TCITEM item1;
item1.mask      = TCIF_TEXT | TCIF_PARAM;
item1.lParam    = (LPARAM)& m_tab1;
item1.pszText   = _T("Titlu Tab1");
pTabCtrl->InsertItem(0, &item1);

//Pozitionarea dialogului
CRect rcItem;
pTabCtrl->GetItemRect(0, &rcItem);
m_tab1.SetWindowPos(NULL, rcItem.left, rcItem.bottom + 1, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER );

m_tab1.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

// al doilea tab
m_tab2.Create(IDD_TAB2, pTabCtrl);
TCITEM item2;
item2.mask      = TCIF_TEXT | TCIF_PARAM;
item2.lParam    = (LPARAM)& m_tab1;
item2.pszText   = _T("Titlu Tab2");
pTabCtrl->InsertItem(0, &item2);

//Pozitionarea dialogului
//CRect rcItem;
pTabCtrl->GetItemRect(0, &rcItem);
m_tab2.SetWindowPos(NULL, rcItem.left, rcItem.bottom + 1, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER );

m_tab2.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
  }

  void CCTabControlDlg::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
  {
if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
{
    CAboutDlg dlgAbout;
    dlgAbout.DoModal();
}
else
{
    CDialog::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
}
    }

  // If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
  //  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
  //  this is automatically done for you by the framework.

  void CCTabControlDlg::OnPaint()
  {
if (IsIconic())
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

    SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()),   0);

    // Center icon in client rectangle
    int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
    int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
    int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

    // Draw the icon
    dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
}
else
{
    CDialog::OnPaint();
}
  }

  // The system calls this function to obtain the cursor to display while the user drags
  //  the minimized window.
  HCURSOR CCTabControlDlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
  {
   return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
  }


  void CCTabControlDlg::OnTcnSelchangeTabcontrol(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
  {
// TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
*pResult = 0;

   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this automatically in MFC by making the parent dialog a `CPropertySheet` and the contained dialogs `CPropertyPage`.

With the way you have it structured currently, you should do a `ShowWindow` for each of the dialogs with one set to `SW_SHOW` and the other to `SW_HIDE` in your `OnTcnSelchangeTabcontrol` function.

Answer (score 2):

You should add your Tabcontrol click event and do the following codes. Dialog pointers pTab1 and pTab2 for each dialog/tab.

```
    void CYourClass::OnNMClickTab1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult) 
    {
        pTab1->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);  
        pTab2->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);  
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            m_tbCtrl.HighlightItem(i,FALSE); 
        }
        switch(m_tbCtrl.GetCurSel())
        {
            case 0: pTab1->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);break;
            case 1: pTab2->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);break;
        }   
        m_tbCtrl.HighlightItem(m_tbCtrl.GetCurSel(),TRUE); 

       *pResult = 0;
    }
```